# can't pass variable from controller to model to handle multiple upload fields in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, model, controller

I have three file inputs in a form (each of them with different name: self_pic, passport_pic, and sic_pic). in a controller that handles the inputs, i assign three names of uploaded image to each different variables and i pass the variables into a function that i already defined in a model, so that i can save the variables that contain names of uploaded image in db. it works fine for two variables and not for one variable. I keep getting error that the variable is undefined.

here's my code in controller

```
                $config['upload_path'] = './asset/image/participant_img';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('self_pic')){
                    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->load->view('reg_participant', $errors);
                } else {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $self_pic = $_FILES['self_pic']['name'];
                }

                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('passport_pic')){
                    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->load->view('reg_participant', $errors);
                } else {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $passport_pic = $_FILES['passport_pic']['name'];
                }

                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('sic_pic')){
                    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->load->view('reg_participant', $errors);
                } else {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $sic_pic = $_FILES['sic_pic']['name'];
                }
                $pictures = array ('self_pic' => $self_pic, 'passport_pic' => $passport_pic, 'sic_pic' => $sic_pic);

                $this->reg_model->simpan($pictures);
                redirect('/registrations_participant', 'refresh');
```

error:

[the error that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibmBS.png)

and also i feel dirty writing that bunch of if's, I try to write them in a loop but i couldn't find how to do it. any idea? or any suggestion how to write them properly. thank you!

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You have a field `self_pic` in database and the value is null when it cannot be (according to your db schema). Verify that (1) the file exists (2) the name of the upload file in the view is spelled verbatim (3) print_r($_FILES); There is also nothing wrong with the way you are uploading the images, a foreach loop would make sense, but you have specific fields and not just multiple files for the "same" field.

Comment: Also if an error does occur there is nothing from stopping the redirect or insert function, could exit after loading the view in the error ifs

Comment: Just want to add that you have a statement to check if the upload worked or not. In your case the `self_pic` upload failed so your code never instanciated the variable $self_pic since this would happen only if the upload worked. As @Alex said, $self_pic was null and it made your simpan function fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the field is null because the file is either too large (thus not uploaded), the upload field name is not correct, or an error occurred and the variable never gets set (which you don't see as you redirect). Try the following code (also integrates a foreach and removes all files on error to prevent orphans).

```
$config['upload_path'] = './asset/image/participant_img';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$upload_fields = array('self_pic', 'sic_pic', 'passport_pic');

$uploaded_files = array();

$error_flag = false;

foreach ($upload_fields as $field_name) {
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // delete files on failure as when the user reuploads to fix
        // whatever error occurs we don't have duplicates!
        if (count($uploaded_files) > 0) {
            foreach ($uploaded_files as $file) {
                @unlink($file);
            }
        }
        $error_flag = true;
        $this->load->view('reg_participant', $errors);
        break; // stop everything...
    } else {
        $uploaded_files[] = $this->upload->data('full_path');
        $data[$field_name] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }
}

// an error occured, don't redirect as then we won't see our error message
// from above view
if (!$error_flag) {
    $this->reg_model->simpan($data);
    redirect('/registrations_participant', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine as i expected, but i still wonder why my the variable $self_pic in my controller return null (I have checked that i didn't do any spell mistake in view, controller, and model).

Comment: It returned null because some error occurred. Remove the redirect and you'll see what the error was. As the variable is only defined in the else aka if no upload error happened that's why it was null. This would have given you a notice if you haven't redirected as well.